# Constrained member functions and explicit template instantiation

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts, explicit-instantiation

G++ and Clang++ agree that the following snippet is not valid C++:

```
template<int dim, int rank>
struct Tensor {};

template<int dim>
double InnerProduct(Tensor<dim, 1> const &, Tensor<dim, 1> const &)
  { return 0.0; }

template<int dim>
double DoubleInnerProduct(Tensor<dim, 2> const &, Tensor<dim, 2> const &)
  { return 0.0; }

template<int dim, int rank>
class Field
{
private:
  static double Dot(Tensor<dim, rank> const &u, Tensor<dim, rank> const &v) requires (rank == 1)
    { return InnerProduct(u, v); }

  static double Dot(Tensor<dim, rank> const &u, Tensor<dim, rank> const &v) requires (rank == 2)
    { return DoubleInnerProduct(u, v); }
};

template class Field<2, 1>;
template class Field<2, 2>;
```

The error message states that even the functions with unsatisfied constraints are instantiated:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘DoubleInnerProduct(const Tensor<2, 1>&, const Tensor<2, 1>&)’
   22 |     { return DoubleInnerProduct(u, v); }
```

I can make it work in a number of ways (for example, declaring `Dot` as templates with a default parameter equal to `rank` to which the constraints are applied), but I expected it to work.

In general, shall I assume that template classes with member functions with constraints depending on their template parameters cannot be explicitly instantiated?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Observations (not explanations): **(A)** If you just _declare_ the `Dot` overloads, the explicit instantiation declarations of `Field<2, 1>` and `Field<2, 2>` compiles successfully. **(B)** Even without removing the definitions, you may explicitly declare the full static member function viable for a given instantiation rather than just the instantiation declaration of the particular class template: `template double Field<2, 1>::Dot(Tensor<2, 1> const &, Tensor<2, 1> const &);`.

Comment: [\[temp.explicit\]/10](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#10) states that _"An explicit instantiation of a constrained template is required to satisfy that template's associated constraints. [...]"_ which may apply here, in the you can successfully supply and explicit instantiation definition for the correct `Dot` overload (as shown in my comment above).

Comment: Moreover, [\[temp.explicit\]/12](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#12) states that: _"An explicit instantiation definition that names a class template specialization explicitly instantiates the class template specialization and is an explicit instantiation definition **of only those members that have been defined at the point of instantiation**."_, which explains why Clang and GCC accepts an explicit instantiation definition of the `Field` class template given that the (static) member functions that for which the given instantiation is invalid are not yet defined.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are explicitly instantiating with e.g. `template class Field<2, 2>;` rather than just declaring a variable `Field<2, 2> foo`? Is it just to understand what happens?

Comment: @ArthurTacca Sometimes, when there are a finite number of possible template parameters, I place the implementation in a cpp file and use explicit template intantiation.

Comment: @metalfox I see, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug of the c++20 experimental implementation of both GCC and Clang.

This is reported as GCC [bug #77595](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77595).

In the c++20 paragraph [temp.explicit]/11:

> An explicit instantiation that names a class template specialization is also an explicit instantiation of the same kind (declaration or definition) of each of its members (not including members inherited from base classes and members that are templates) that has not been previously explicitly specialized in the translation unit containing the explicit instantiation, **provided that the associated constraints, if any, of that member are satisfied** by the template arguments of the explicit instantiation ([temp.constr.decl], [temp.constr.constr]), **except as described below**. [...]

According to this c++20 adendum *"provided that the associated constraints, if any, of that member are satisfied"* means that only one of the two `Dot` overload shall be explicitly instantiated.

The bolded clause "*except as described below*" was there in the c++17 standard. It does apply to the first clause "*An explicit instantiation that names a class template specialization is also an explicit instantiation of the same kind (declaration or definition) of each of its members*". The interpretation of this exception has not changed with c++20. Probably that the commitee overlooked that, grammaticaly, it could be correct to apply the exception to the c++20 adendum.

Below is the [c++17 version](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.explicit#8) of this paragraph:

> An explicit instantiation that names a class template specialization is also an explicit instantiation of the same kind (declaration or definition) of each of its members (not including members inherited from base classes and members that are templates) that has not been previously explicitly specialized in the translation unit containing the explicit instantiation, **except as described below.**

In this shorter sentence the meaning is clear.

Comment: Very convincing. That "except as described below" is indeed confusing, but if you know it was already there... It is curious though that this bug wasn't looked at. A. Sutton and the GCC team fixed most of the concept bugs for the GCC 10 release.

Comment: A patch fixing it for GCC 10.3 has been accepted: https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-patches/2020-July/550980.html

Answer (score 2):

#### Explicit class template instantiation definitions are also explicit instantiation definitions of those members that have been defined at the point of instantiation

Consider the following simplified example:

```
template<int rank>
struct A {};

template<int rank>
struct Field {
    void dot(A<rank>) requires (rank == 1) { (void)(1); }
    void dot(A<rank>) requires (rank == 2) { (void)(2); }
};
```

[[temp.explicit]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#11) states [**emphasis** mine]:

> An explicit instantiation **that names a class template specialization
> is also an explicit instantiation** of the same kind (declaration or
> definition) **of each of its members** (not including members
> inherited from base classes and members that are templates) that has
> not been previously explicitly specialized in the translation unit
> containing the explicit instantiation, **provided that the associated
> constraints**, if any, **of that member are satisfied by the template
> arguments of the explicit instantiation** ([temp.constr.decl],
> [temp.constr.constr]), **except as described below.** [...]

Which implies that an explicit instantiation definition that names only a class template specialization of `Field`, say

```
template struct Field<1>;
```

will also lead to the explicit instantiation definition of the `dot` overload which fulfills the constraint expression  `requires (rank == 1)`, but not for the overload with a constraint expression `requires (rank == 2)`. However, the **except as described below** part leads us to [[temp.explicit]/12](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#12), which states [**emphasis** mine]:

> An explicit instantiation definition that names a class template
> specialization explicitly instantiates the class template
> specialization and is an explicit instantiation definition **of only
> those members that have been defined at the point of instantiation**.

Meaning that, for the simplified example above (followed by the explicit instantiation definition for `Field<1>`, as above), the passage above indicates the explicit instantiation definition of **both** `dot` overloads, as both have been defined at the point of the explicit instantiation definition of `Field<1>`. This, however, means an ODR-violation as there will be two definitions of `Field<1>::void dot(A<1>)`.

```
// Not OK.
template<int rank>
struct A { };

template<int rank>
struct Field {
    void dot(A<rank>) requires (rank == 1) { (void)(1); }
    void dot(A<rank>) requires (rank == 2) { (void)(2); }
};

template struct Field<1>;

int main() {}
```

yielding the following error on Clang:

> ```
> error: definition with same mangled name '_ZN5FieldILi1EE3dotE1AILi1EE' as  another definition
>        void dot(A<rank>) requires (rank == 2) { }
> ```

Note that we may provide an explicit instantiation definition for, particularly, the `dot` non-template member of the `Field` class template for a given specialization of the latter, and GCC and Clang will happily accept it, indicating that the constraint expressions are respected when explicitly instantiating the overloaded, constrained functions:

```
// OK.
template<int rank>
struct A { };

template<int rank>
struct Field {
    void dot(A<rank>) requires (rank == 1) { (void)(1); }
    void dot(A<rank>) requires (rank == 2) { (void)(2); }
};

template void Field<1>::dot(A<1>);

int main() {}
```

but not when they are, as described above, implicitly given explicit instantiated definitions as per the [temp.explicit]/12 quote above, as this seems to provide separate instantiation definitions for both members (without respecting the constraint expression) and thus violating ODR.

The different behaviour from the compilers between the explicit instantiation definition of the class template specialization vs a non-template member function of the specialization is somewhat peculiar, but possibly the difference is that for the latter case,  [[temp.constr.constr]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.constr#2.sentence-3) applies [**emphasis** mine]

> [...] **Overload resolution requires the satisfaction of constraints on functions** and function templates.

---

If we only *declare* but don't define the second overload, it will not be instantiated as part of the explicit instantiation definition (i.e., [[temp.explicit]/12](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#12) does not apply for it) of `Field<1>`, and we will no longer have an ODR-violation:

```
// OK.
template<int rank>
struct A { };

template<int rank>
struct Field {
    void dot(A<rank>) requires (rank == 1) { (void)(1); }
    void dot(A<rank>) requires (rank == 2);
};

template struct Field<1>;

int main() {}
```

---

Now, why is this not failing for an implicit instantiation?

As per [[temp.inst]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#3.1) [**emphasis** mine]:

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes
>
> (3.1) the implicit instantiation of the declarations, **but not of the
> definitions**, of the non-deleted class member functions, member
> classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members, member
> templates, and friends; and [...]

such that the following example is accepted by both Clang and GCC:

```
template<int rank>
struct A { };

template<int rank>
struct Field {
    void dot(A<rank>) requires (rank == 1) { (void)(1); }
    void dot(A<rank>) requires (rank == 2) { (void)(2); }
};

int main() { 
    Field<1> f{};
    (void)f;
}
```

where, as per [[temp.inst]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#4), the `dot` overloads will not be instantiated as the `Field<1>` specialization is not referenced in a context that requires their definitions to exist.

Finally, however, we may note that the implicit instantiation of the `dot` static member function of the `Field` class template will respect the constraint expression, and instantiate the overload which fulfills the constraint on the `rank` non template parameter of the particular class template specialization:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int rank>
struct A { };

template<int rank>
struct Field {
    void dot(A<rank>) requires (rank == 1) { std::cout << "1"; }
    void dot(A<rank>) requires (rank == 2) { std::cout << "2"; } 
};

int main() { 
    Field<1>{}.dot(A<1>{}); // "1"
}
```

This is likely governed by [[temp.constr.constr]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.constr#2.sentence-3), as quoted above.

Comment: *"SFINAE ... constraint expressions needs to be applied to a dependent name"* Unlike SFINAE, `requires` *can* disable a non-template member function of a template class. It does work if you remove the explicit instantiation and try to call the function.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I just noticed that that is indeed the case ([DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7wYi3urg2FvIzkWV)), but was unsure whether this was actually valid or is violating ODR? I guess, as per your comment, this is a different between constraint expressions and meta-programming SFINAE? Do you know which parts (possibly [\[temp.const\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr)) that governs this?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat From your comment and my answer above (first part), it would seems as 1) explicit instantiation definitions of non-template member functions of a class template will not respect the requires clause, whereas 2) if they are implicitly instantiated, as per [temp.inst]/4, the constraint expression will be respected when deciding which member overload that is to be instantiated (on the on-need basis)?

Comment: I didn't look into this feature too much, but your second comment sounds correct.

Comment: @dfri It is perfectly valid. There are plenty of such uses in the standard. Have a look at the range adaptors. Concepts are much better than sfinae.

Comment: See, for example, [[iota.view]](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.iota.view) `end`. Nevertheless, I believe that the rest of your answer is right, modulo the last paragraph.

Comment: @metalfox I entirely removed the SFINAE part and just added my reflections on the differences explicit/implicit instantiation; I'm still not sure what governs the correctness of the implicit case, but hopefully someone can chime in with a relevant comment or edit.

Comment: I think that what makes my code invalid is [temp.explicit]/10, which seems to imply that all constraints must be satisfied. Explicit template instantiation seems to involve no partial ordering of constraints, but the standard wording is extremelly hard for me to understand.

Comment: @metalfox Yes and now we also have [\[temp.explicit\]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#11) from [AndyG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62661723/4573247) that would motivate the opposite of our arguments. I fully agree that the standard wording is tricky on this one.

Comment: Could it be that the essential difference here is actually [\[temp.constr.constr\]/2-sentence-3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.constr#2.sentence-3)? _"Overload resolution requires the satisfaction of constraints on functions and function templates"_